# How to do both Add and Update in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to do both update and add in same action method in ASP.NET Core by Entity Framework Core, but after making an update to a lists of records in the database, I cannot add a new record to the table that the updates were made in.

What is my mistake?

After adding a list in the `Tbl_TechnicalProp_Values` previous records that I updated them removed and new records added:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,TopicID,Title")] Tbl_TechnicalProp tbl_TechnicalProp, string[] ProdPropValUp, string[] ProdPropVal)
{
     _context.Update(tbl_TechnicalProp);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

     var q = _context.Tbl_TechnicalProp_Values
                     .Where(a => a.TechnicalPropID == tbl_TechnicalProp.ID)
                     .ToList();

     int n = 0;

     foreach (var item in q)
     {
           item.Value = ProdPropValUp[n];
           _context.Update(item);
           n++;
     }

     _context.SaveChanges();

     var qTechProp = _context.Tbl_TechnicalProp
                             .Where(a => a.ID == tbl_TechnicalProp.ID)
                             .Single();

    qTechProp.Tbl_TechnicalProp_Values= new List<Tbl_TechnicalProp_Values>();

     for (int i = 0; i < ProdPropVal.Count(); i++)
     {
         if (ProdPropVal[i] != null && ProdPropVal[i] != "")
         {
            qTechProp.Tbl_TechnicalProp_Values.Add(new Tbl_TechnicalProp_Values()
            {
                Value = ProdPropVal[i]
             });
          }
     }

      _context.Update(qTechProp);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @FarzanMirheydari, These codes have a logical error,after update a list of records in Tbl_TechnicalProp_Values, if i want to add new records to Tbl_TechnicalProp_Values the previous  that I updated them removed and new records instead of them added.

Comment: Are you sure you need to call _context.Update(item) within the for loop? Normally EF Core tracks changes so they will get updated when you call savechanges anyway.

Comment: Thanks @JohanHerstad ,I can solve this problem by removing the last _context.Update(qTechProp) with make a new Tbl_TechnicalProp_Values that doesn't related to previous updated recordes